# What are the 24 hour regex for 'angular2-input-mask'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to input 24 hour time format using 'angular2-input-mask'.following mask i am trying. What will be the correct mask for valid 24 hour time format.

```
 this.mask = [/[0-2]/, /^([0-9]|2[0-3])/, ':', /[0-5]/, /[0-9]/];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to apply a mask for the hour with **angular2-input-mask**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="setTime($event)" [(value)]="timeStr" [textMask]="getMask()" />
```

**TypeScript:**

set time on key up

```
setTime(e):void{
  this.time = e.target.value;
}
```

define the mask relative to `this.time`

```
getMask():{
  mask: Array<string | RegExp>;
  keepCharPositions: boolean;
} {
  return {
    mask: [/[0-2]/, this.time && parseInt(this.time[0]) > 1 ? /[0-3]/ : /\d/, ':', /[0-5]/, /\d/],
    keepCharPositions: true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved my problem this way.

**HTML**

```
 <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" [(ngModel)]="input_time" (ngModelChange)=changeRegex(input_time);type="text"/>
```

**TypeScript**

Write this following code in angular 2 component.

```
 public mask: Array<string | RegExp> = [/[0-2]/,/\d/, ':', /[0-5]/, /\d/],

 changeRegex(input_time){
    if(input_time.charAt(0) == '2'){
       this.mask[1]=new RegExp('[0-3]')
    }else{
       this.mask[1]=new RegExp('\d')
    }
  }
```